# How to check if user is logged in or not in forms based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I want to implement forms based authentication manually in my website.

I am using `Web.config` file for data store

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
         name=".ASPXAUTH"
         path="/"
         requireSSL="false"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         defaultUrl="~/Admin/OrderHistory.aspx"
         cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="false"
         >
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="Admin" password="adm123$"/>
      <user name="Administrator" password="adm234%"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users ="?" />
  <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

There is a `Login.aspx` page at root level in that im using ASP.NET login control to get username and password.

Everything works fine but when the user is `logged in` and manually go to `login.aspx` page, its not redirect the user to defaultUrl page.

I want to redirect the user to a specific page/defaultUrl page, if he is logged in and came manually to login.aspx page

How to do it?

### Login Button-Click

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginUser.UserName, true);

    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
    if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

    //Redirect to Default page
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Hi after adding the above code browser showing following message with error `This webpage has a redirect loop`

Comment: Use it on Login.aspx. not default.aspx

Comment: i wrote that in login.aspx page load only

Comment: may be we have to remove the `!` in if statement

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the strategy of session for this.

If a session is established then redirect the user to a specific page or else direct him to login.

You can refer for more info here http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/

Comment: But, then how can one stay on that page only and not redirect to the Login.aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

use the forms attribute defaulturl="xyz.aspx"(your URL) in your web.config file

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        if (!Request.UrlReferrer.Equals("http://localhost:1360/login_page.aspx"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("ERROR ==>? 404");
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.